Publishing an article despite the outcomes are not what we wanted
For my master's thesis (6 months), I worked very hard for the project with the supervisor. I wrote all the codes everything by myself from scratch. However, the results we have now are not what we expected them to be, and are complicated to explain. My supervisor does not seem to be interested in this project anymore. I have verified the code and am confident the results are correct.
However, the supervisor does not want to continue working on this anymore and has not advised me on how to explain the results mathematically. He does not answer my queries and is not willing to meet me to discuss this any further. I am not sure what to do. I feel very agitated given that I spent 6 months on this work and that I cannot get a paper out of this.
Can I ask him if I can publish some results for which we have explanations in a journal or at least whether my master's thesis can be published in a journal? Also, can someone please suggest a journal that does not charge money from authors to publish?
I do not know how academia works. I do not have any immediate contact to whom I can ask how these things work. Nevertheless, I feel that I have worked hard on this and my work deserves to be published, rather than being stacked away on a shelf. Therefore, I cannot let it go.

Is there a reason why you want to publish this separately in a journal? Unless results are exceptional (in every meaning of the word) they just go into your master thesis and that’s it.

@MisterMiyagi I think this is a dangerous attitude. In experimental sciences it contributes to a huge bias problem in published research. In other fields, it results in a lot of wasted time on solutions that others have already found ineffective.

@BryanKrause Not sure what attitude you are referring to. That work from MSc does not end up published as papers is the absolute standard I know, least of all because frankly most just isn’t notable; there’s so many MSc theses, no one has time to read them all. Most need at least the wider framework of a PhD or group project for proper, thorough context. Mind, a) I said "exceptional" and not "good"/"nice"/… results and b) expect the thesis itself to be published via the university; this isn’t meant to hide data.

@MisterMiyagi The attitude that results should only be published if they're exceptional. I agree there is a difference with some MSc work that is not intended to produce original research, but if it's intended to produce original research then the intent should be to publish that work, whether it's a piece of a larger project or stands on its own.

@BryanKrause I see the publishing of the data covered by publishing the thesis itself. No need to do so twice in most cases.

Usually a thesis is not "published" in a way that makes it reasonably accessible to others.

I would argue the same if it ends up in a paper crammed on top of everything else that goes on in an MSc deadline. Being in a trash publication doesn’t make data accessible, it just makes it published.

"Can I ask him if" <- Always yes, if you ask your question respectfully and fairly. Even if it's a silly question - you're the suprevisee/apprentice and they are your supervisor, you're allowed to ask stupid questions. Not that your question is stupid.

Maybe it's field dependent, but at least in my part of physics, no-one would expect to get a paper out of 6 months master-level work. I know @BryanKrause didn't like it, but a publication at that level would be exceptional in every meaning of the word. If you are lucky it's enough for a group internal presentation. Maybe this is just a case of mismatched expectations ?

@MisterMiyagi The topic for my thesis is not studied before. However, my results do not follow what the professor expected, therefore, he does not know how to explain those results. And, he does not want to pursuse this further. I have been trying to figure out my own but it is not working. He is not suggesting references either.

Note that a master's thesis doesn't necessarily have to have a result/explanation like you're thinking about. My master's thesis covered two years near the beginning of a 10-year research project. My thesis discussed the work we did, the problems we solved along the way, and the data we gathered, but it wasn't until years later that we even had the terminology to explain the results, much less the theory.

@Marianne013 We've published work from physics undergrad senior thesis. It wasn't very exciting, but with a little work, they reviewed fine and ended up in well-known physics journals for not very exciting work.

Research is about contributing meaningfully to the field you are working in. Sometimes results are not what we expect, but they may still add to the knowledge pool in the field. Other times, results are not what we expect, but publishing these results does not contribute significantly to the field. In either case, researchers may have worked incredibly hard and spent months (or often, years) on their research.
You mentioned you are a master's student (I am assuming MA or MSc). Usually, at this stage, research projects or theses are not yet at a publishable level. For example, there may be explanations for your results that you do not have the skillset or knowledge to understand (yet) or your thesis will have to undergo major revisions (whether those are writing or methodological revisions - each of which can take months or even years) before it is publishable. Perhaps these things do not apply in your case and your thesis is indeed at a publishable level, but these things are important to consider if they have not crossed your mind!
I can understand your frustration, given that you have worked on your thesis for so long and seem to have put in a lot of effort. Bring this up with your advisor again and discuss with them whether publishing at least the results that you are able to explain well is sensible. If they still refuse, ask them for some feedback or why these results are not publishable - it might be that you are overlooking some details that they are able to identify.
As for your question about which journal to publish in: this would depend on your field and the topic of your thesis. One thing I would do as a student is look up where the articles I referred to for my thesis were published (provided that they were in the same field, had a similar topic or followed a similar methodology). Doing this can give you a fair idea of your options. Some journals have open-access or other fees.

to back up your point about it being unusual to publish a masters thesis in a journal - I got an extremely high mark for my masters thesis and won a national award, and still didn't publish it in a journal - it would have required more work than I had time for to get it to a publishable state.

Hard to bring something up with someone and discuss things is that someone is simply stonewalling them, as seems to be the case here.


Can I ask him if I can publish some results for which we have explanations in a journal or at least whether my master's thesis can be published in a journal?

Sure, you can ask him. But, based on your description, it sounds like he may either not answer, which would be a way of answering "no"; or he may explicitly answer "no". Prepare yourself for the possibility that this might happen, and accept that that does not mean he is a bad person or has bad intentions, but may simply mean that he genuinely does not think the results are interesting enough to be publishable.

I do not know how academia works. [...] Nevertheless, I feel that I have worked hard on this and my work deserves to be published, rather than being stacked away on a shelf. Therefore, I cannot let it go.

One of the ways in which academia works is that publishing is not a reward for hard work. The criterion for whether something can be published is whether it is new knowledge that interests people. Research projects — even ones that involve hard work — do not always lead to such knowledge. Sometimes you find new knowledge that doesn't interest people. Other times you may find knowledge that is interesting but turns out to be already known.
We have all worked hard on projects that didn't succeed, at least in the limited sense of not leading to results that are publishable. One has to be philosophical about such things, accepting that failure is a part of academic life. Alternatively, one can be philosophical in a different way, embracing the view that each project is a learning experience, teaching us interesting things and helping us grow to become better researchers and better and wiser humans. In that sense, there is no such thing as a "failure".
That is not to say that you are not justified in being disappointed about this outcome. Not all outcomes are created equal, and some are definitely better than others. But it is what it is. I hope you will find success (or more precisely, publishable results) with your next project.

You don't do research to prove a point. You do it to learn what is actually true, whether it is what you expected or not. If the methodology is valid then the results tell you something about the question you asked, and in physics, something about the world. Anomalous seeming results can actually lead to new research directions.
I don't know whether all of that is valid in your case, of course.
You, along with others considered authors, can certainly submit a paper to a reputable journal. You may or may not be able to do so alone, depending on the contributions of others, including your advisor. If you do submit, you will get feedback from reviewers at the journal on the quality of the research.
Yes, you can ask the advisor about publication. It might be required to do so if they can be considered a co-author. It would be nice if they agree, but if not, you should get a reason why not.
Caveat: Yes, some people do in fact do "research" to prove a point. But that isn't really valid, especially when the "methodology" is biased toward a given result. If you know the answer before you start then there is really nothing to research.

And we have all done projects that did not work out. The best ones don't work out the way you thought they would, but instead revealed something more interesting. The worst ones, well, just don't work out.

As noted, you can ask.
When you ask and what you do with
the answer could also be important.
As you seem to be getting a master's degree out of it,
I'd suggest waiting until after it is awarded
before doing anything that might tick him off.
That the results were not what your professor
expected suggests that they are noteworthy.
If he says no, explicitly or otherwise,
you might or might not try to publish anyway.
If you do, it might be an advantage
to already have your degree.
You should almost certainly mention
the professor in the paper,
but I'd balk at listing him as co-author.
Regardless of what you tell him,
the editor might regard him as the
author with whom to communicate.
Also, the professor, even if he
does not try to stop publication,
might not want to be listed as co-author.
If he does not want to be mentioned at all,
honor that.
